# Creating "own" part page

Tags: table-of-contents, titles, koma-script, page-numbering

First of all, I am sorry for my english.

I tried to create my own part page in a new .tex-document which is included in main.tex:

```
\stepcounter{part}
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\thepart.\hspace{1em}NamePart}

\begin{titlepage}
    \centering
    {\hspace{1pt}}
    \par \vspace{4cm}
    {\huge \sffamily \bfseries \thepart. NamePart}
    \par \vspace{1cm}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.3]{SomePicture}
    \par \vspace{0.5cm}
    {\textcolor{red}{\rule{0.7\textwidth}{2pt}}}
    !here!
    {\textcolor{red}{\rule{0.7\textwidth}{2pt}}}
\end{titlepage}
```

main.tex:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,oneside]{scrbook}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\include{document with the code above}
\chapter{Chapter One}
\section{Section One}
\section{Section Two}
\chapter{Chapter Two}
\section{Section Three}
\end{document}
```

But with this I have multiple Problems:

- the page number is not printed
- in the table of contents the entry is displayed but the hyperef does not work
- I would like to add a small table of contents for the part (where I marked !here! in the code) but I don't know how

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! You seem to be confusing a title page and a part. For part, you should take a look to `titlesec`. It has a companion package, `titletoc`.

Comment: Also, please always provide a small but complete, compilable example document that can be used to reproduce your current output.

Answer (score 2):

Do not misuse `titlepage` environment for a part page. Your class is a KOMA-Script class, so you can redefine `\partlineswithentryprefix`. For the part TOC, you can load package `etoc`.

Example:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,oneside]{scrbook}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}% needed with older TeX distributions
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{etoc}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=4cm]{part}
\renewcommand\partformat{\thepart\autodot\enskip}
\renewcommand\partheadmidvskip{}
\addtokomafont{part}{\huge}
\renewcommand\partlineswithprefixformat[3]{%
  #2#3
  \ifstr{#1}{part}{%
    \par \vspace{1cm}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=.3]{example-image}\par
    {\textcolor{red}{\rule{0.7\textwidth}{2pt}}}\par
    \etocsettocstyle{}{}%
    %\etocsettocdepth{\chaptertocdepth}%
    {\normalsize\localtableofcontents}
    {\textcolor{red}{\rule{0.7\textwidth}{2pt}}}\par
  }{}%
}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\part{NamePart}
\chapter{Chapter One}
\section{Section One}
\section{Section Two}
\chapter{Chapter Two}
\section{Section Three}
\part{NextPart}
\chapter{Chapter Three}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

---

If there are **different pictures for different parts** or part pages without a picture, then you can define a macro for the name of the picture file:

```latex
\newcommand*\partimage{example-image}
\newcommand\setpartimage[1]{\def\partimage{#1}}
```

Then you have to change the `\includegraphics` line to

```latex
\ifstr{\partimage}{}{}{\includegraphics[scale=.3]{\partimage}\par}%
```

Example:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,oneside]{scrbook}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}% needed with older TeX distributions
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{etoc}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=4cm]{part}
\renewcommand\partformat{\thepart\autodot\enskip}
\renewcommand\partheadmidvskip{}
\addtokomafont{part}{\huge}
\renewcommand\partlineswithprefixformat[3]{%
  #2#3
  \ifstr{#1}{part}{%
    \par \vspace{1cm}
    \centering
    \ifstr{\partimage}{}{}{\includegraphics[scale=.3]{\partimage}\par}%
    {\textcolor{red}{\rule{0.7\textwidth}{2pt}}}\par
    \etocsettocstyle{}{}%
    %\etocsettocdepth{\chaptertocdepth}%
    {\normalsize\localtableofcontents}
    {\textcolor{red}{\rule{0.7\textwidth}{2pt}}}\par
  }{}%
}
\newcommand*\partimage{example-image}
\newcommand\setpartimage[1]{\def\partimage{#1}}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\setpartimage{example-image-a}
\part{NamePart}
\chapter{Chapter One}
\section{Section One}
\section{Section Two}
\chapter{Chapter Two}
\section{Section Three}
\setpartimage{example-image-b}
\part{NextPart}
\chapter{Chapter Three}
\setpartimage{}
\part{Part without picture}
\chapter{Chapter Four}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: @hiyi See my updated answer.